# How to use variable in js using style tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I use javascript variable in style tag?
I tried with jQuery:

```
var height = $('.replyComment').height();
$('div.replyComment').append('<style>div.replyComment:before{content: ""; border-left: 1px solid #e1e1e1;position:absolute; left:38px; top:-20px; height:'+ height +';}</style>');
```

So where am I wrong? What I have to do to assign height of a div in div:before using height variable?

Comment: you can use `css()`, for applying css

Comment: Main problem - you need to add 'px': height:'+ height +'px;...etc... css needs measure unit, jQuery height() returns just number.

Answer (score 3):

Try to append it to `head`.

```
$('head').append('<style>div.replyComment:before{content: ""; border-left: 1px solid #e1e1e1;position:absolute; left:38px; top:-20px; height:'+ height +'px;}</style>');
```

Make sure that you have to add `px` to height.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's CSS function

`css({"propertyname":"value","propertyname":"value",...});`

Like that:

```
var height = jQuery('.replyComment').height();

jQuery('div.replyComment:before').css({
  "content":"",
  "border-left":"1px solid #e1e1e1",
  "position":"absolute",
  "left":"38px",
  "top":"-20px",
  "height": height
});
```

More info: [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/css/), [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

```
jQuery('div.replyComment').css('height', height);

div.replyComment:before{
    content: ""; 
    border-left: 1px solid #e1e1e1; 
    position:absolute; 
    left:38px; 
    top:-20px; 
}
```

Add the css to your style sheet, then target the div height specifically when needed.

Answer (score 0):

From [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/height/#height2) you can see how you can use the `height()`, not only to get the *height* of an **element**, but to set it too. Just pass the new *height* as an argument: `.height(value)`

Beside that. It is not a good practice to set **inline** css styles. I rather use [`jQuery.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [`jQuery.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) functions from jQuery to change the styling of an *HTML element*.

For your example it will look something like this:

css

```
.styles-to-add:before{
  content: ""; 
  border-left: 1px solid #e1e1e1; 
  position: absolute; 
  left: 38px; 
  top: -20px; 
}
```

javascript

```
$('div.replyComment').addClass('styles-to-add');
```

And then independently you can set the height of any element like:

```
var height = $('.replyComment').height();
$('div.replyComment:before').height(height);
```